# pandas questions about argmin and timestamp

Tags: pandas

```
final_month = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-01')
df_final_month = df[df['week'] >= final_month] 
df_final_month.iloc[:, 1:].sum().argmax()


index = df.set_index('week')
index['storeC'].argmin()
```

the code above is correct, i just don't exactly understand how does it work inside. i have some questions:

1.the type(week) is datetime, the reason why set final_month as Timestamp is that the datetime is almost as same as Timestamp, they recognise each other in Python?

2.about the argmax(), and argmin(), for the df_final_month.iloc[:, 1:].sum().argmax(),  i removed sum() and tried like df_final_month.iloc[:, 1:].argmax(), it returns

```
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argmax'`
```

why is it?   why the second code doesn't need a max() or something to call argmin(), what's the requirement for using argmin()/argmax() ?

please explaining the details of how python or pandas deal with these data, the more detail the better.

thanks!

i am new in Python.

Comment: What does your DataFrame `df` look like? I would say it has a column named `week`, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, week is a column with format " 2016-01-01".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is Timestamp almost as same as datetime?

Here is quote from `pandas` documentation itself:

> TimeStamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangable with it in most cases

In fact, if you look at source code of `pandas` you will see that [`Timestamp` actually inherits from datetime](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L105). Here is code to check these statements are true:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
ts = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')
dt == ts # True
isinstance(ts, datetime.datetime)  # True
```

> 2. Why calling `argmax` method on DataFrame, without calling `sum` throws an error?

Because DataFrame object doesn't have `argmax` method, [only Series do](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html). And `sum`, in your case, returns a Series instance.